# "Blogs I'm following" folder doesn't show up in Google Reader settings nor in the Android app

Tags: google-reader, blogger, blog

Here, one can see that Blogger has created a custom folder in my Google Reader, automagically housing all the blogs I follow there:

[image]

But, that seems to be the only place this folder appears! It's not to be found in the settings, as one can see here:

[image]

Nor can it be seen in the Google Reader Android app. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blogs I'm following` is a rather new feature. That's probably the reason it's not in the Android app yet.

For the settings, `Blogs I'm following` is a special folder maintained by Google Reader itself, so you are probably not allowed to change anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly new , it's been around 4+ years :
http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2008/08/get-your-blogger-following-fix-in.html

Technically it's maintained by Blogger, meaning that whatever you unsubscribe or move from that folder in Reader will reappear, unless you unfollow the blog in Blogger (or via the followed blog itself).

The Listen folder for Google Listen is (or was) slightly newer at ~2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gReader, which is an Android App, you can see all your feeds without doing the workaround I mentioned above.

Making a new folder works as well.